# logging all tcp connections

Tags: java, logging, tcp, connection

How to log tcp connections in java? I have some code which is calling various services using tcp (http or binary), I'd like to see on the console when something is being called (connection started). What is the best way to add logging of such events?

I was thinking about adding aspects on urlconnection, on socket, etc, but maybe there is an easier way? Is there some single java class used for every connection which is not too low level and could be "intercepted" somehow?

Comment: System.out.println... in your method call?

Comment: If it was my method and a single one...

Comment: Could you just put a wrapper around the functions you want to be logged? Then you can just call your wrapper, this creates better abstractions for your code too!

Comment: Look, I dont call it directly, here is some underlying "layer" which is communicating with stuff. I want to be able to log and investigate the connections being made without using sniffers. I cannot "wrap" it, there are hundreds of classes using various APIs. Something is performing poorly and I want to know what

Comment: Well perhaps it would have been a good idea to tell us that in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know in advance *where* the poor performance stems from, so what exactly are you going to put aspects on?

Your best bet - considering the requirements you had mentioned - is to use a profiler. JProfiler would be a good place to start.

Comment: Regular profiler does not meet my needs as the problem with time-consuming calls does not repeat too often, I want to analyze the logs later.

Comment: What about a tool such as Wily Introscope, then? it can probe your code over time and provide you statistics and logs. Very powerful tool.